# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(\, x\,\right)\,{\rm d}x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I encountered this integral in the quantum field theory calculation. Can I do this:

$$
\left. \int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(\, x\,\right)\,{\rm d}x
=x\ln\left(\, x\,\right)\right\vert_{0}^{1}
-\int_{0}^{1}\,{\rm d}x
=\left. x\ln\left(\, x\,\right)\right\vert_{\, x\ =\ 0}\ -\ 1
$$

So the first term looks divergent. But Mathematica gives finite result and the integral is $-1$. Why isn't the first term divergent ?.

Comment: I changed the tags because the previous ones where not related to the question.

Comment: *the first term looks divergent* - Appearances can be deceiving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use L'Hopital's Rule to resolve the indeterminate form: $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}{\ln x\over x^{-1}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}{x^{-1}\over -x^{-2}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}(-x)=0$$

Comment: Uh, I tried L'Hopital's Rule, but used it this way $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{1/\ln x}=-\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\ln^2x$... Which one is correct?

Comment: They're both correct, but your method won't really help you find the limit.

Answer (score 3):

interpret $\int_0^1 \ln x dx$ as the signed area of the region bounded by $x = 0, y= \ln(x)$ and $y = 0$ this is the negative of the area of the region bounded by $x = e^y, y = 0$ and $x = 0$(interchange $x$ and $y$ in the previous boundary). the area of latter region is $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^y dy = 1.$  so $\int_0^1 \ln(x) dx = -1.$

another way to think of the same thing is in the first area computation you have the infinitesimal rectangles parallel to the $y$-axis in the latter the infinitesimal rectangles parallel to $x$-axis.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use L'Hopital's rule to evaluate $\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln x$.

Answer (score 2):

Or alternatively, use the substitution $x=e^y$.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before posting and using integration by part, got one term looks like $ye^y|_{y\rightarrow -\infty}$ then stuck.

Comment: Yeah fair, that's another situation where you would use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Oh yes! I didn't try because $-\infty\notin\mathbb R$. But it works formally.

Comment: L'Hopita's rule extends to $\pm\infty$ by noticing $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x^{-1}).$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\begin{gathered}
  \int\limits_0^1 {\ln xdx}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to {0^ + }} \int\limits_\varepsilon ^1 {\ln xdx}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to {0^ + }} \left( {\left. {\left( {x\ln x} \right)} \right|_{x = \varepsilon }^{x = 1} - \int\limits_\varepsilon ^1 {dx} } \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to {0^ + }} \left( { - \varepsilon \ln \varepsilon  - 1 + \varepsilon } \right) \hfill \\
   =  - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to {0^ + }} \varepsilon \ln \varepsilon  - 1. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
On the other hand, by the L'Hospital rule, we have
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to {0^ + }} \varepsilon \ln \varepsilon  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to {0^ + }} \frac{{\ln \varepsilon }}
{{\frac{1}
{\varepsilon }}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to {0^ + }} \frac{{\frac{1}
{\varepsilon }}}
{{ - \frac{1}
{{{\varepsilon ^2}}}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to {0^ + }} \left( { - \varepsilon } \right) = 0.$$
So
$$\int\limits_0^1 {\ln xdx}  =  - 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the general log integral, $$I_n=\int_0^1\log^n(x)\ dx$$
note that we are after $I_1$ and define the exponential generating function $G(t)$,
$$G(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{I_n}{n!}t^n=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(t\log(x))^n}{n!}\ dx=\int_0^1x^t\ dx=\frac{1}{1+t}$$
for $t>-1$ and expanding the result as a geometric series in the same region,
$$\frac{1}{1+t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nt^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nn!}{n!}t^n$$
comparing coefficients,
$$I_n=(-1)^nn!.$$
The first four non-zero log integrals are,
$$\begin{align*}
&\int_0^1\log(x)\ dx=-1,\quad\int_0^1\log^2(x)\ dx=2 \\
&\int_0^1\log^3(x)\ dx=-6,\quad\int_0^1\log^4(x)\ dx=24.
\end{align*}$$